# Only Update a Subfield in "Firebase" Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a subfield on firebase but I couldn't figure out how to **only** update **one** field at a time.

**This is how my Firebase table looks like;**

[image]

**And this is how I'm trying to do it:**

[image]

**And lastly, this is how it looks after the update:**

[image]

This is seriously taking time and I couldn't find any videos that shows how to update a field only. Everyone just updates the document as a whole. Thanks in advance people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbRefUser.updateData({"properties.currentCashBalance": currentCashBalance + ourTransaction.amount
});

Use this. I think it will work.